# Use class imported from a module in multiple subfiles

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm currently rewriting a project of mine using ecmascript 2015.
I have a module.js file in which I have two classes. I would like to use those classes in two files (index.php and page.php which is a dynamic generated page included in index.php).

My treefile looks like this:

```
 /..
    modules.js // Where I store my classes
    page.php // This also contains a <script> part in which I would like to use my classes
    index.php // Where I import my .js files
    script.js // Where I would also like to use my classes
```

I have imported my classes in the index.php file like this:

```
<script type="module" src="js/modules.js">
    import * from "./js/modules.js"
</script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

And my module file looks like this:

```
export { Blabla1 , Blabla2 };

class Blabla1 {
    constructor(......) {
        .....
  }

class Blabla2 {
    constructor(......) {
        .....
  }
}
```

The problem is that I can't initiate any of the class I've imported in script.js and page.php and get stuck with:

```
ReferenceError: Blabla1 is not defined
```

If anyone has any guess on my problem I would really appreciate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally this should work:

```
<script type="module">
    import { Blabla1, Blabla2 } from './js/module.js';
    var bla1 = new Blabla1();
</script>`
```

```js
export { Blabla1 , Blabla2 };

class Blabla1 {
    constructor() {
        console.log('In Blabla1');
  }
} // It's missing

class Blabla2 {
    constructor() {
        console.log('In Blabla2');
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi,

I've tried this and this work but only internally, I mean that I can only create "Blabla1" objects where you created "bla1" but I can't create objects elsewhere otherwise they're not recognized.


Second thing, I would idealy want to load this script before script.js. Is there a way to do so ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want export/import a class from one.js file to another.js file you should use this code below.

```
export class Person {
  static logme() {
    console.log('Hi');
  }
}
```

And then call it from another.js file

```
import Person from './another.js';
console.log(Person.test());
```

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't help in my case.